# Mask Video SVG shapes

Tags: html, css, svg, video, mask

I'd like to insert a video to a shape SVG.

The shape looks like this :[image: Shape]
I exported them to .svg

I tried use `mask` CSS and create the shape with CSS to use `overflow: hidden` but nothing.

I need your help please !
Thanks

Comment: Thank you, but I would like to see the video only in the form and not on the outside

Comment: well, the pen did show you the technique,  your image is translucide ... plain black & white is required with mix-blen-mode here ... i guess you did not turn the shadow into white instead pink as it is...

Comment: ... okay  2 examples https://codepen.io/gc-nomade/pen/dyyXQeK , https://codepen.io/gc-nomade/pen/eYYzQrg (black&white)  ... any feedback ?

Comment: @G-Cyr, It's perfect ! Thank you so much.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use   [clip-path - CSS:](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/clip-path) and as a plus  [object-fit](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/object-fit)

> The clip-path CSS property creates a clipping region that sets what
>   part of an element should be shown. Parts that are inside the region
>   are shown, while those outside are hidden.

just apply it to the video without using svg.

```
video {
    object-fit: cover;
    clip-path: url(resources.svg#c1);
}
```

Here is a demo

```css
*{
  box-sizing: border-box;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0
}
figure{
  width: 100vw;
  height: 400px;
  position: relative;
  background-color: red; 
  overflow: hidden
}
video{
  object-fit: cover;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  clip-path: polygon(100% 0, 88% 63%, 58% 94%, 46% 94%, 13% 63%, 0 0);
}
figcaption{
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  text-align: center;
  bottom: 28vh;
  font-size: 3vw;
  font-weight: 900;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  z-index: 2;
}
```

```html
<figure>
  <video controls controls autoplay preload="metadata" buffered loop>
 

      <source src="https://www.w3schools.com/html/mov_bbb.mp4"
              type="video/mp4">

      Sorry, your browser doesn't support embedded videos.
  </video>
  <figcaption>My Nice video</figcaption>
</figure>
```